# can not render after camera deleted

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, converters

in the problem of today is about unity 
well i 'm always in the beginnings so i just took a full asset from the store
so while applying some changes i just get a crazy error saying that no cameras rendering 
in the start of the project everything work smoothly 
this is the script linked to the camera 
this script just trying to make a map generator not completed yet

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapGen : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public GameObject[] flats=new GameObject[4];
    public GameObject flat;
    public int x; 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    { 
        Vector3 pos = flat.transform.position;

        x = pos.x; 
        Debug.Log("position :: "+ x ); 

        if(x%26 == 0)
        { 
            Destroy(flats[0]);

            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                flats[i] = flats[i + 1];
            }

            flats[3] = flat; 

            Debug.Log("position "+x);       
        }
    }
}
```

all works great but when trying this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapGen : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public GameObject[] flats=new GameObject[4];
    public GameObject flat;
    public int x; 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    { 
        Vector3 pos = flat.transform.position ;
        x=(int) pos.x; 
        Debug.Log("position :: "+ x ); 

        if(x%26 == 0)
        { 
            Destroy(flats[0]);

            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
               flats[i] = flats[i + 1];
            } 

            flats[3] = flat; 
            Debug.Log("position "+x);       
        }
    }
}
```

it just give me the error after running the game just like if the camera was destroyed and as you can see it is just this expression that was changed

```
x=pos.x;
```

to

```
x=(int) pos.x;
```

by the way the variable flat is referring to the main camera

Comment: The change is rounding down the value pos.x to nearest integer while old code was using a decimal value

Comment: So one by one you destroy `Destroy(flats[0]);`, then you shift the array by one ... so after a while all objects in your array are destroyed, right? ... the `x` actually seems not to matter too much but only changes when this is happening exactly ... Is there another script involved? Your script alone seems to not make much sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you end up assigning your camera to the array and end up moving it up to [0] position and destroying it

```
flats[3] = flat;

flats[i] = flats[i + 1];

Destroy(flats[0]);
```